# why allocating too much memory to android studio can cause degrade the performance

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In android studio/intellij ide when you wanted to define the memory allocation you will see this warning:

> similar to allocating to little memory allocating too much memory will
> degrade the performance

why?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make the heap too big?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192583/can-i-make-the-heap-too-big)

Comment: not really, could you elaborate more on it

Comment: Aside from allocating too much that the OS is starving for RAM, a larger heap means more objects in GC and longer pauses https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225252/java-slower-with-large-heap-no-excessive-gc-ing