# Jenkins heap space

Tags: java, performance, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins on Windows 2016 server with the following defenitions in jenkins.xml:

```
-Xrs -Xmx2G -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"
```

But the problem that we get an error:

```
exception while collecting data: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

and the server stuck.
After monitorung the master, we have seen that java heap is 512 and not 2G. How can it be? 
From the Master monitor screen:

```
OS: OS Windows NT (unknown), , x86/32 (4 cores)
Java:   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, 1.8.0_66-b18
JVM:    Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, 25.66-b18, mixed mode   The server mode has much better performance than the client mode, you should consider using the server mode if your are not in development
PID of process: 7960
Server: Server jetty/9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
Webapp context: 
Start:  11/28/17 2:15 PM
JVM arguments:  -Xrs
-Xmx2G
-Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle
-Xmx512M
Mean age of http sessions (min):    6
Memory: Non heap memory = 83 Mb (Perm Gen, Code Cache),
Buffered memory = 0 Mb,
Loaded classes = 22,254,
Garbage collection time = 6,007 ms,
Process cpu time = 156,718 ms,
Committed virtual memory = 438 Mb,
Free physical memory = 13,245 Mb,
Total physical memory = 16,383 Mb,
Free swap space = 16,199 Mb,
Total swap space = 19,327 Mb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that you have 2 options `-Xmx` in the monitor screen.

Beside verifying what's in **jenkins.xml** file, have a look at environment variable(s) like:

`JAVA_OPTS`, `MAVEN_OPTS` or `ANT_OPTS`.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot find -Xmx512M defined in my jenkins.xml. I edited this config to run installed x64 installed java and not the default in: <executable> c:\java\jdk1.8\bin\java.exe</executable> and added -d64 -server to the <arguments> but still same result :(

Comment: @DimaKreisserman do you have **JAVA_OPTIONS** defined in your environment?

Comment: you are the best! there it was :). Now the question is what is the correct way to define it? should I put the same value in jenkins.xml and JAVA_OPTIONS? what value to put? suppose the VM runs Jenkins only and has 16 G RAM memory.

Comment: @DimaKreisserman glad you got it sorted! About what to put where, please remember that the JAVA_OPTS took precedence. Was it because it was lower value, or because it got added later? ... and at the end of the day, do you run many other java applications on that box?

Comment: This VM runs jenkins only. I've read that java doesn't use heap memory only, so it's wrong to put all RAM memory on -Xmx. What would you suggest?

Comment: If it's only Jenkins, then it doesn't matter much, which parameter dictates the final size. Regarding heap sizing, there is no simple answer - you have to monitor and see. Have a look at this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651225/how-to-choose-the-jvm-heap-size

Comment: I found great article explaining how to tune Jenkins gc: https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/11/21/gc-tuning/